# Entity Framework "Enable-Migrations" command generates Configurations.cs file encoded in ANSI. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, nuget

I am using EF Code First with migrations for a project and I have stumbled upon a strange behavior:

Executing the "Enable-Migrations"-command in the Package Manager Console generates a "Migrations" folder and "Configurations.cs" file. When I check the encoding of the "Configurations.cs" in Notepad++ it shows that it is ANSI encoded.

When I create an arbitrary file in Visual Studio 2010 it's always encoded in UTF-8. Why does NuGet generate the file in another encoding?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Probably because powershell creates things in ANSI, and VS creates things in UTF-8, but don't quote me on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got around to properly investigating this...

The files (Configuration.cs and the individual migration files) are actually being saved as UTF-8 without a file signiture. This format is indistinguishable from ANSI unless non-ANSI characters appear somewhere in the file. Tools like Notepad++ will only show it as UTF-8 if there are non-ANSI characters in the file. This is because a UTF-8 file with only ANSI characters is 100% compatible with the ANSI format.

If you have non-ANSI characters in your context type name, table names, etc. things will work as you expect, and Notepad++ will report the file format as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for claryfying! I didn't think of ANSI being a subset of UTF-8 and trusted Notepad++ blindly :-)

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file is actually stored as a template embedded in an assembly in the NuGet package and is then processed and copied into your project when Enable-Migrations is used. The stored template is an ANSI file and hence the file you get is an ANSI file. You should be able to re-save it as UTF-8--the runtime won't care.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any specific reason why the template is ANSI-encoded? And wouldn't that mean that by default any seeds with crazy characters wouldn't be correctly stored in the db?

Comment: I don't think that there is any particular reason other than all our source files are ANSI and so this was ended up that way too. I'll follow up with others and see if it makes sense to make it UTF-8 by default.

Comment: "by default any seeds with crazy characters wouldn't be correctly stored in the db", oh, that's exactly what happened in our project and we spent some time to figure out why our DB values are wrong despite correct nvarchar and collation settings. It was because of the ANSI-encoded migration files which had been running on a server with different default ANSI codepage for non-Unicode programs.